# cannot read property name of underined react.js axios

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to make a simple HTTP request to an API but am getting an error saying name is undefined. here is the JSON  data below... ideally i would like to have a list of each trail and display each one , im not sure how exactly I can achieve this.  Any help is greatly appreciated!  thanks!!

JSON

```
   {
    "trails": [
    {
    "id": 7004682,
    "name": "Royal Arch",
    "type": "Featured Hike",
    "summary": "A classic Boulder hike to a natural arch with great views.",
    "difficulty": "blueBlack",
    "stars": 4.4,
    "starVotes": 76,
    "location": "Boulder, Colorado",
    "url": "https://www.hikingproject.com/trail/7004682/royal-arch",
    "imgSqSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7003311_sqsmall_1430066482.jpg",
    "imgSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7003311_small_1430066482.jpg",
    "imgSmallMed": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7003311_smallMed_1430066482.jpg",
    "imgMedium": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7003311_medium_1430066482.jpg",
    "length": 3.3,
    "ascent": 1311,
    "descent": -1312,
    "high": 6917,
    "low": 5691,
    "longitude": -105.283,
    "latitude": 39.9997,
    "conditionStatus": "All Clear",
    "conditionDetails": "Dry",
    "conditionDate": "2018-05-27 00:23:03"
    },
    {
    "id": 7000130,
    "name": "Bear Peak",
    "type": "Featured Hike",
    "summary": "A must-do hike for Boulder locals and visitors alike!",
    "difficulty": "blueBlack",
    "stars": 4.5,
    "starVotes": 62,
    "location": "Boulder, Colorado",
    "url": "https://www.hikingproject.com/trail/7000130/bear-peak",
    "imgSqSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7005382_sqsmall_1435421346.jpg",
    "imgSmall": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7005382_small_1435421346.jpg",
    "imgSmallMed": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7005382_smallMed_1435421346.jpg",
    "imgMedium": "https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/7005382_medium_1435421346.jpg",
    "length": 5.7,
    "ascent": 2641,
    "descent": -2640,
    "high": 8396,
    "low": 6100,
    "longitude": -105.2755,
    "latitude": 39.9787,
    "conditionStatus": "All Clear",
    "conditionDetails": "Dry",
    "conditionDate": "2018-05-31 08:25:18"
    },
    {
}
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import axios from "axios";
import './App.css';


import UserForm from "./components/UserForm";

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    name: "",
    stars: "",
    icon: ""
  }
  getUser = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const address = e.target.elements.address.value;
    if (address) {
      axios.get(`https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=40.0274&lon=-105.2519&maxDistance=10&key=200279581-dd891420fa2c470dbb683b34e017062a`)
      .then((res) => {

        console.log(res);


         console.log(res.trails.name);
        const name = res.trails.name;
          const  stars = res.trails.stars;
          const icon = res.trails.imgMedium;
        this.setState({ name });
           this.setState({ stars });
           this.setState({ icon });
      })
    } else return;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <header className="App-header">
          <h1 className="App-title">HTTP Calls in React</h1>
        </header>
        <UserForm getUser={this.getUser} />
        { this.state.name ? <p>Name: { this.state.name }</p> : <p>Please enter an address.</p> }

            { this.state.stars ? <p>stars: { this.state.stars }</p> : <p>Please enter an adress.</p> }


              {this.state.icon && <figure > <img className='img-fluid' src={`https://cdn-files.apstatic.com/hike/img/w/${this.state.icon}.jpg`} /> </figure> }
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trials is an array of objects. `console.log(res.trails[0].name);` should work.

To achieve the 2nd part of your question. You'd could do.

```
constructor() {
  super()
  this.state = {trails: [], isLoaded: false}
}
componentDidMount() {
   axios.get(`https://www.hikingproject.com/data/get-trails?lat=40.0274&lon=-105.2519&maxDistance=10&key=200279581-dd891420fa2c470dbb683b34e017062a`)
    .then((res) => {
      this.setState({trails: res.trails, isLoaded: true});
  })
}
render() {
  if(this.state.isLoaded) {
    return <div>
      {this.state.trails.map((trail) => {
        return <div> <p>{trail.name}</p> </div>
      })}
    </div>
  } else {
    return <div>loading data....</div>
  }
}
```

The idea is that you build a list of html elements from the response data and render that. This becomes part of component state so that you can add or remove from the list using setState() later on. The reason for the isLoaded variable is that render needs to render something in the meantime.

Comment: thanks for the help , im getting new error saying  Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: what is your console.log(res) logging?

Comment: ok i figured out the problem its res.data.trails.name , but how do i display all of them in the list  instead of just one ? do i use map or?

Comment: obviously you can add more or less detail to it as you see fit. But the concept your looking for is above.

Comment: let me know if that works for you and if it does could you mark it as answer for the next person with this problem

Comment: thanks for the clarification , i seem to get an error sayint that traiList is not defined , maybe you have to set state for trailList?

Comment: sorry i made a mistake it should be {this.state.trails} NOT {trailList}. That will work for you when you try that. i've updated my answer to include this.

Comment: so if i console.log the trail.name trail.stars it shows everything but its not displaying anything in the screen ,

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/172816/discussion-between-matt-pengelly-and-leon-bogod).